# JS Promises.all issue

Tags: javascript, promise

I've got an issue regarding `Promises` and `Promises.all(x)`.
The issue at hand is, that promises seem to be executing twice, both before being added to the `Promises.all()` and afterwards.
Here's the piece of code I'm using for testing right now:

```js
let num = 5;
const promises = [];
function stackPromises(total, maxVal){
    console.log("Start!");
    for(let i=0; i<total; i++){
        promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if(num < maxVal){
                let message = num + " is less than " + maxVal;
                console.log(message);
                resolve(message);
            }else{
                let message = num + " is not less than " + maxVal;
                console.log(message);
                reject(message);
            }
        }).catch(function(fMessage){
            console.log(fMessage);
        }));
        maxVal--;
    }
    console.log(promises);
}
Promise.all(promises).then(function(sMessage){
    console.log(sMessage);
}).catch((fMessage) => {
    console.log(fMessage);
});

stackPromises(8, 10);
```

And this is the response I get back:

```
Start!
proxyConsoleLog.js:12 5 is less than 10
proxyConsoleLog.js:12 5 is less than 9
proxyConsoleLog.js:12 5 is less than 8
proxyConsoleLog.js:12 5 is less than 7
proxyConsoleLog.js:12 5 is less than 6
proxyConsoleLog.js:12 5 is not less than 5
proxyConsoleLog.js:12 5 is not less than 4
proxyConsoleLog.js:12 5 is not less than 3
proxyConsoleLog.js:12 (8) [Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise]
proxyConsoleLog.js:12 5 is not less than 5
proxyConsoleLog.js:12 5 is not less than 4
proxyConsoleLog.js:12 5 is not less than 3
```

I've noticed that the last 3 entries, which get rejected repeat twice. I could be wrong but does this mean that every single promise is being executed twice? And if that is the case how am I supposed to just initialize them before activating them until they get added to `Promise.all()`?

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Comment: Either step through your code and what the `console.log()`s that are executed, or add a unique identifier to each of them and then check the console and you should see where these "duplicated" entries come from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the **order** you run your code in.

1. You create an empty array
2. Your pass that empty array to `Promise.all`
3. You populate that array with promises

The promise created by `Promise.all` will resolve when all **zero** of the promises you passed to it have resolved.

And then its just a race for how many of the promises created by `stackPromises` will resolve before that triggers.

Populate the array **before** passing it to `Promise.all`.

Comment: Right, is there a way to initialize promises but not run them at the same moment? Can I just create a bunch of promises, add them to an array, and then pass that array to Promises.all()?

Comment: "Right, is there a way to initialize promises but not run them at the same moment?" — No. Promises run when they are created.

Comment: What seems to be the point of Promise.all() then? I thought that's the main reason I would use it in the first place, in order to run several promises at once and if at least one of them fails, the rest of them stop executing instantly.

Comment: The point is to do something once multiple promises resolve. e.g. so you can fetch data from multiple HTTP requests and then merge it once all the pieces have arrived.

Comment: So basically, Promise.all() just makes an array of rejects and resolves? It doesn't run the promises for the second time? Then by analyzing those rejects and resolves I can bundle them up and create whatever is necessary?

Comment: "So basically, Promise.all() just makes an array of rejects and resolves?" — No. An array of the resolved values. It rejects if any of the promises reject.

Comment: "It doesn't run the promises for the second time?" — Correct.

Answer (score 2):

> I've noticed that the last 3 entries, which get rejected repeat twice. I could be wrong but does this mean that every single promise is being executed twice?

The reason you're seeing two logs is just that you have two console.log statements for the error case. One is here:

```
else {
  let message = num + " is not less than " + maxVal;
  console.log(message);
  reject(message);
}
```

And then a second time a few lines later:

```
}).catch(function(fMessage){
  console.log(fMessage);
}));
```

The reason there's a delay between them is that calling .catch on a promise creates a new promise, and when one promise resolves/rejects, the next code in the promise chain doesn't execute immediately, but rather is queued up as what's called a "microtask". It will run synchronously, but only after the current call stack empties and any other microtasks ahead of it have run, and the promise.all's .then callback is ahead of it in the queue.